# MongoDB instance with Alteryx Designer

Tags: mongodb, alteryx

I have a question about the MongDB installation that comes with Alteryx Server.

Is that instance of Mongo a desktop version or is it a server version?

Comment: There is no such thing as a desktop version of MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Alteryx Server 10.0 is shipped with MongoDB 3.0.4 Community Edition.  More information on the Alteryx Server Installation can be found here: http://downloads.alteryx.com/Documentation/Alteryx%20Server%20Installation%20Guide.pdf